# Which SDK should I use to visualize medical images in 3D?

Tags: image-processing, visualization, dicom, medical

I need to process DICOM formatted medical images and visualize them in 3D, also do some image processing on these images on real-time. Therefore, I am asking this question to learn which SDK has better real-time characteristics for medical visualization and image processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visualization Toolkit (VTK) is an open-source, freely available software system for 3D computer graphics, image processing and visualization.

You can find details [here](http://www.vtk.org/).

Or another solution would be the modifying or utilizing 3D engine that supports volume rendering.

Moreover, for computer vision algorithms, [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

[osgVolume](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/wiki/Community/Tasks/osgVolume) is an add-in to the popular [openscenegraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/) library for doing this

Comment: Thanks Martin for your time, I will also check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use GDCM+VTK. In 2D simply use gdcmviewer. In 3D you need to build gdcmorthoplanes.

Ref:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=Gdcmviewer

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=Using_GDCM_API

Answer (score 0):

You could check out MITK (http://mitk.org) which combines the already mentioned VTK with the Insight Toolkit (http://www.itk.org) for image processing. Another option to start from could be Slicer (http://www.slicer.org), but this depends on the license you need.

Answer (score -1):

In a uni we were taught Matlab for DICOM file processing. I think it has pretty nice and easy to use plugins for that as well. The end results were that using Matlab I was able to do all kinds of DICOM image processing, filtering and so forth.

As you probably know, Matlab is not SDK but a complete environment. Nevertheless you can write scripts to achieve normal application behavior: Create windows, buttons, images, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I need an SDK to develop my algorithms on it based on medical image processing